# Magento 2: Set cron schedule dynamically from frontend

Tags: magento2, email, cron, programmatically, schedule

I want to set schedule of cron job from values chosen by the customer from the frontend.
I have created checkboxes on checkout page through which I want to set the schedule of email reminders chosen by the customer.

I want to trigger email reminders based on options chosen by the customer on the checkout page before place order.

The options would be like: [image]

Comment: and your question is...? :)

Comment: My question is how can  I implement this?

Comment: which part? what have you tried?

Comment: I want to trigger email reminders based on options chosen by the customer on the checkout page before place order.. I have updated the question.